# Osascript - No output

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, terminal, applescript

**Here is my little test script:**

```
do shell script "cd ~/Desktop; ls -l1"
set x to the result
tell application "Finder" to activate
```

When I'm running it via Script Editor, it works fine.

When I'm trying the very same thing via the terminal, like `osascript myscript.scpt`, it's not working at all - no output whatsoever.

Btw, I've tried even invoking it via a Cocoa NSTask. One time it worked and then it keeps returning a weird `Class _NSZombie_OS_xpc_data is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.` error message (`osascript` not Cocoa).

What's going on?

---

**P.S.** I don't know whether that's relevant at all, but after trying a `top` in the terminal I noticed an instance of `osascript` running(?!), though killing it didn't do any good either...

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `osascript` command, you get only the result of the last AppleScript's command.

So, the last command is `tell application "Finder" to activate`, this command return nothing.

To get the result of the `do shell script` command, use this:

```
set x to do shell script "cd ~/Desktop; ls -l1"
tell application "Finder" to activate
return x
```

Comment: OK, since I've made a lot of progress since I first posted the question. Let me put it this way: Is there any other way to get the intermediate events/replies from `osascript` (NOT the final result), other than using `AEDebugReceives=1`?

Comment: You can return many variables that contains text or numbers like this : `return var1 & linefeed & var2 & linefeed & var3` , otherwise I don't know of any other way.

Comment: If you run that very same script above (without returning anything) you'll notice it also outputs the intermediated events (under the "events" and "replies" tabs. One way to get this output is by setting `export AEDebugReceives=1` in the terminal, restart Finder and re-execute the script as you normally would! (e.g. `osascript yourscript.scpt`) Try it ;-)

Comment: I try it on Mavericks, and i have this `aevt('aevt'\'ansr' transactionID=0 returnID=9873 sourcePSN=[0x0,64064 "Finder"] timeout=0 eventSource=3 sourceUID=501 sourceGID=20 sourceEUID=501 sourceEGID=20 sourcePID=1044 auditToken=[501,501,20,501,20,1044,100004,1044]{  })`.

Comment: With the script above? Just that? - I mean it printed out something like that, but only in the very end. Before that the intermediate events (with the Desktop contents I mean) were printed just fine. (P.S. Yosemite, but I can't see how this might have affected it... Apple has historically been very... fond of Apple Events lol)

Comment: In the Terminal the result of the do shell script is incomplete,  I get the last name of the 18 items on the desktop.  
I Have 18 names under the "events" in the AppleScript editor. 
But the result is correct in the Terminal with this AppleScript's command `do shell script "cd ~/Desktop; ls -l1" without altering line endings`. 
So, for me, using `AEDebugReceives=1` is correct to see the result in the Terminal, but not to use the result in a shell command.